# How do I hide several lines if php variable is empty?

Tags: php, variables, show-hide, is-empty

As a learner in PHP, I'm struggling to hide from displaying several lines, if a chosen variable is empty. I can get this to work on a basic level, but am lost when the content to be hidden gets more complicated. The concept I am aiming at is this:

```
<?php if (isset($g1)) { ?>
((This part should not display if variable $g1 is empty))
<?php } ?>
```

My code looks like this:

```
<?php if (isset($g1)) { ?>
<a href="img/g1.png"  class="lightbox"  rel="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php print $g1; ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded wbdr4" src="img/g1.png">
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

In the above, the tooltip does not display when variable g1 is empty, but the rest does. I'm new here so, I hope I've formatted my question correctly. Help appreciated.

Comment: It looks like they are using that.. But their coding style is very unreadable in my eyes.

Comment: Use if ($g1 != NULL) { //img tag }

Comment: I suggest taking a look at my answer first, cause every single answer here misunderstood your question. (OR I am the idoit and everyone else is right :P )

Comment: u can use the empty() function.it will handle all. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Just a note to say that I appreciate the help given. This is an amazing community! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if (isset($g1) && $g1!='') { ?>
<a href="img/g1.png"  class="lightbox"  rel="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php print $g1; ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded wbdr4" src="img/g1.png">
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this code:
<?php if (!empty($g1)) { ?>
((This part should not display if variable $g1 is empty))
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use if `empty()` function:

```
<?php if (isset($g1) && !empty($g1)) { ?>
((This part should not display if variable $g1 is empty))
<?php } ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (isset($g1) && $g1 !== '') { ?>
((This part should not display if variable $g1 is empty))
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: if its not empty, then surely it must be set

Comment: isset just checks for null, you can still check for empty strings with empty()

Comment: No need to. Just like `isset()`, `empty()` won't issue Warnings when used with undeclared variables, and should return `FALSE` if it's undeclared.

Answer (score 0):

The `isset()` function checks if the variable has been set, even if to an empty string. There's the `empty()` function which checks if the variable is not set or set to empty string.

```
<?php
$x = '';
if (isset($x)) print('$x is set');
if (empty($x)) print('$x is not set or is empty');
if (isset($x) && empty($x)) print('$x is set and is empty');
if (!empty($x)) print('$x is set and not empty'); // won't emit warning if not set
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer that seems to be going a totally different route than everyone else, which i have no idea why.

To do what OP wants, one way is to expand the php tag to include all.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($g1)) { 
        echo "<a href='img/g1.png'  class='lightbox'  rel='tooltip' data-original-title='".$g1."' data-plugin-options='{\"type\":\"image\"}'>";
        echo "<img class='img-responsive img-rounded wbdr4' src='img/g1.png'>";
        echo "</a>";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

hiding something is pretty easy in php you can use it in several ways and here is how it would look like

```
<?php if(isset($g1) == ""): ?>
   //The $g1 is empty so anything here will be displayed
<?php else: ?>
   //The $g1 is NOT empty and anything here will be displayed
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `isset($g1) == ""`... really?