# Hiding lines if php variable is empty

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a php code inside a variable, that prevents a text print if a variable is empty. The code is as follows:

```
$file = 'file.txt';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $counter += file_get_contents($file);
}
file_put_contents($file, $counter);

$Item1 = @$_POST['Item1'];
$Item2 = @$_POST['Item2'];

$filename = "mydata.txt";
$txt = "\n";

$f_data= '
'<?php if (isset($Item1) && !empty($Item1)) { ?>' Item 1 : '.$Item1.' '} ?>'
'<?php if (isset($Item2) && !empty($Item2)) { ?>' Item 2 : '.$Item2.' '} ?>'
';

$file = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($file,$f_data);
fclose($file);
}
else
{
die("error");
}
```

I am facing problem at:

```
'<?php if (isset($Item1) && !empty($Item1)) { ?>' Item 1 : '.$Item1.' '}'
'<?php if (isset($Item2) && !empty($Item2)) { ?>' Item 2 : '.$Item2.' '}'
```

This code basically prevents the "Item 2 : " from printing if the @$_POST['Item2'] from the form is empty.

The code I am using for this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24857671/5008955

I am getting the error "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'**" with this line.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why you are using again php tags it's already it in php only

Comment: you can try this one $f_data= "<?php if (isset($Item2) && !empty($Item2)) { ?>" 'Item 2 : '.$Item2.'}';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be entering PHP tags and then leaving them twice.

```
'<?php if (isset($Item1) && !empty($Item1)) { ?>' Item 1 : '.$Item1.' '} ?>'
'<?php if (isset($Item2) && !empty($Item2)) { ?>' Item 2 : '.$Item2.' '} ?>'
```

You should have the following:

```
'<?php if (isset($Item1) && !empty($Item1)) { ?>' Item 1 : '.$Item1.' ' <?php } ?>'
'<?php if (isset($Item2) && !empty($Item2)) { ?>' Item 2 : '.$Item2.' ' <?php } ?>'
```

You are also checking if `$Item1` and `$Item2` are set, which regardless if there is any data received from the form, those variables will be set as you have defined them.

So you could make it:

```
'<?php if (!empty($Item1)) { ?>' Item 1 : '.$Item1.' ' <?php } ?>'
'<?php if (!empty($Item2)) { ?>' Item 2 : '.$Item2.' ' <?php } ?>'
```

Or one step further:

```
'<?php echo (empty($Item1)) ?: " Item 1 : $Item1 "?>'
'<?php echo (empty($Item2)) ?: " Item 2 : $Item2 "?>'
```

You may also wish to write it like this:

```
// Set the $f_data variable so that if neither $Item1 or $Item2 
// have any data, your `fwrite($file,$f_data);` won't fail.

$f_data = '';

if (!empty($Item1)) {
    $f_data .= "Item 1 : $Item1 ";
}
if (!empty($Item2)) {
    $f_data .= "Item 2 : $Item2 ";
}
```

Comment: I still get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'" when I use '<?php if (!empty($Item1)) { ?>' Item 1 : '.$Item1.' ' <?php } ?>'

Comment: Still getting the same error. Can you show me the whole code so that I could know 'm not doing anything wrong?

Comment: What data are you entering for `$Item1` and `$Item2`?

Comment: The $Item1 and $Item2 data is retrieved from form submission via $Item1 = @$_POST['Item1'];

Comment: Sorry I meant, what data are you entering in to the form when you are testing it?

Comment: Hello. The type of the input is text and normal text data is entered. But the question in this matter is if the field is left empty the "Item :" shouldnt appear.

Comment: Does it say what it was expecting (in the error you get)?

Comment: No. Just "unexpected 'if' (T_IF)".